# Does anyone know why my react map gl is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-map-gl

I wanted to know if react typescript was good so I was trying it out.
I am running into problems I've never had.

here is my code

```
function Map() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    latitude: 37.7577,
    longitude: -122.4376,
    zoom: 8
  });

  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken="API key here"
      onViewportChange={(viewport: any) => setViewport(viewport)}
    />
  );
}
```

This is the error I get

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/User/Drive/Coding/src/components/interactive-map.js:287
  284 | 
  285 | /* eslint-disable max-statements */
  286 | const InteractiveMap = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
> 287 |   const parentContext = useContext(MapContext);
  288 |   const controller = useMemo(() => props.controller || new MapController(), []);
  289 |   const eventManager = useMemo(
  290 |     () =>
```

I'm not sure what the cause could be so if you need any more information please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call, you can read

> Do not call [hooks] in event handlers.

And that is what you are doing...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with `react-map-gl`, is with the way you're using hooks. Hooks can only be used directly inside function components, because of the way react sort and call them (using arrays) you can read more about that on the official website of React.

Comment: AFAIK, hook handler might be passed as a prop to another component. Seems to be that `map-gl` calls this handler under condition

Comment: I think the error is straightforward. in the file `C:/Users/User/Drive/Coding/src/components/interactive-map.js` at line **287** you used hooks inside `forwardRef`'s callback which is not a functional component.